# Used Github Desktop and now terminal not detecting changes

Tags: github, github-desktop

I used Github Desktop to perform a complex merge and now I've noticed that my terminal is not picking up any changes when I run:

```
git status
```

I need to first push the code up to `origin` using Github Desktop, then pull down in my terminal in order for the changes to take place.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that github desktop somehow made a clone of the repo in a new location which is why my terminal wasn't locating the file changes.  The github desktop repo was located at: `/Users/NAME/Documents/GitHub/repo-name`.  I'm sure this is something I screwed up during setup but figured I'd throw this out there in case it helps anyone!